# updating DefaultListModel on another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I have a program that need to update the content of `JList`, which is `DefaultListModel` on another thread. Since the number of contents may change from time to time, so I just clear all content and add new content into `DefaultListModel` when updating. But seems I ran into an issue that `JFrame` starts refreshing while my thread is doing update. I got exceptions like this

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

Here is an **example of the code**

```
    DefaultListModel model;
    JList jList;
    JScrollPane jScrollPane;

    Thread thread;
    public Frame() {
        this.setTitle("ASM_SIMULATOR");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        model = new DefaultListModel();
        jList = new JList(model);
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);

        jList.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        jScrollPane.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);

        this.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane);

        this.setVisible(true);

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {

                    makeData();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        thread.start();
    }

    public void makeData() {
        System.out.println("makeData()");
        model.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.addElement((int) (Math.random() * 100));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You violate the basic "all Swing component should be accessed/modified on the Event Dispatch Thread (=EDT), and on the EDT only" twice in that code snippet.

1. Your main method should wrap the `new Frame()` call in an `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` or some similar method
2. Your model-update thread changes the model on a background thread. Updating the model will fire events which are received by the `JList`, on which the `JList` updates itself (again, on the wrong thread).

Two possible solutions:

- create a new `DefaultListModel` on your background thread, and replace it in one go on the EDT.
- keep updating the existing model, but make sure the updates happen on the EDT.

Comment: Do you know any good and CONCISE tutorial on that? I want to read a bit more about how EDT works and how to avoid threading problems.

Comment: @Vito See [the Swing concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is don't

Swing is not thread safe.

What you need to do is either use a `SwingWorker` to build the model and use its `done`/`process` method to apply it back to the view or use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to continue using your thread, but sync updates back to the Event Dispatching Thread

Have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details

Answer (score 2):

1. you have issue with [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
2. have to wrap `model.addElement((int) (Math.random() * 100));` into `invokeLater`
3. correct way could be start workers `Thread` from `Runnable#Thread`, or use `SwingWorker`
4. output from `SwingWorker`s methods `publish()` and `process()` could be doen on `EDT`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not that simple. Only the GUI thread should be allowed to update the GUI, so any other thread needs to forward any updates to the GUI thread via `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater`. In your case you can probably just wrap the entire `makeData` method, since all it does is update the GUI:

```
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          makeData();
                      }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Note that now the code of `makeData` will execute on the GUI thread. In other cases when you're doing other time-consuming work that does not involve the GUI you should use `InvokeLater` in a more fine-grain manner to keep the UI thread as free as possible.

**Edit**: Looking more carefully at your code, I noticed that all you're doing is a timed update of the GUI every 200 ms. You can do this much easier with `javax.swing.Timer`:

```
int delay = 200; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        makeData();
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```